# Math random with user inputting the min and max

Tags: javascript, math

I would like the user to enter their own upper and lower numbers, so math random can choose a random number between them. For some reason, the number chosen goes over the upper number, can anyone advise?
http://jsfiddle.net/artworkjpm/w54e9bsw/

```
function getRandomNumber( upper, lower) {
    var lower = prompt("give me your lower number");
    var upper = prompt("give me your higher number");
    if (isNaN(lower) || isNaN(upper) ) {
      throw new Error("you need to select a number");
    };
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (upper - lower)) + lower; 
    }

    document.write("<h2>" + getRandomNumber() + "</h2>");
```

Comment: Not really related but you should check that upper is high and lower is low.

Comment: You have to know that `prompt()` always returns `string`. So your function will always throw exception

Comment: Could you please print out what lower and upper is to make sure those are correct? also print out Math.floor(Math.random() * (upper - lower)) My guess is that prompt is returning a string rather than an int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prompt returns an string that may not be the int you want. Try changing the string to int.

Answer (score 4):

```
function getRandomNumber() {
  var lower = parseInt(prompt("give me your lower number"));
  var upper = parseInt(prompt("give me your higher number"));
  if (isNaN(lower) || isNaN(upper) ) {
    throw new Error("you need to select a number");
  };
  var preNumber = Math.random() * (upper - lower);
  if(Math.random() < 0.5){
     return Math.ceil(preNumber) + lower; 
  } else {
    return Math.floor(preNumber) + lower; 
  }      
}

console.log(getRandomNumber());
```

Comment: @Vladimirs How can it return 1 with input 2 and 4? But you are right that it will not return the upper but at maximum upper-1

Comment: Maybe a jsfiddle or something? Here is my jsfiddle showing that getting 1 is impossbile

https://jsfiddle.net/hy05fqqp/

Comment: Sorry my bad.. didn't realize that you are adding lower after floor. I tested with Math.floor(Math.random() * (upper - lower) + lower)

Comment: Ah, wait, I was only answering half your comment. I guess I didn't read the question well enough. Let me see if I can make this a little tidier.

Comment: What do you think of this now?

Comment: Now is better. However I looks like not all expected numbers will have same chance because Math.random() returns 0 but doesn't return 1.

Comment: yes, unfortunately. But since javascript stores numbers is a 64-bit double precision float, the difference in range between 0 to .5 and .5 to .99999 is so small, that this works unless you need absolute precision.

Answer (score 2):

Use parseInt method

return Math.floor(Math.random() * (parseInt(upper) - parseInt(lower))) + parseInt(lower);

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used parseInt in the prompt and it worked:

```
function getRandomNumber( upper, lower) {
    var lower = parseInt(prompt("give me your lower number"));
    var upper = parseInt(prompt("give me your higher number"));
    if (isNaN(lower) || isNaN(upper) ) {
      throw new Error("you need to select a number");
    };
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (upper - lower)) + lower;
    }

    document.write("<h2>" + getRandomNumber() + "</h2>");
```

Answer (score -2):

You have a mistake in your last instruction ( return )

You should do this, 
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * upper) + lower);

verified !!